# Pull a user's Google+ or Gmail list of contacts and their email addresses

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm building an app in which I'm trying to allow a user to log in through Google+ (currently using the Google API PHP Client Library) and pull their entire contact list in to decide if they want to send an email to their list from my app. I can easily see how to allow the user to grant access to multiple permissions through different Google APIs through setting scopes.

I'm struggling to see either what scope I should be setting when making a request and/or what API should accomplish pulling a logged in user's contact list along with each contact's email address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you have to pull contacts with an valid OAuth request through the Google Contacts API. On the documentation page for the Google Contacts API, Google says:

> The Google Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts. Contacts are stored in the user's Google Account; most Google services have access to the contact list.

You can find the documentation here.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Comment: I'll be implementing this post-haste! :)